# StartsWith query using LIKE is returning the wrong results on a non ascii column

Tags: sql-server, collation, like

I want to query a table for entries that begin with a specific fragment of text.

I am under the impression that the LIKE operator is a way to do this, so if I wanted to find all rows that have a Column2 that starts with "a" then I would do that with a query such as the following

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM Table1
WHERE Column2 LIKE 'a%';
```

I have found that using a query like this returns unexpected results.

Here is an example:

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDB;
GO

USE TestDB;
GO

CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    Romanian NVARCHAR(MAX) COLLATE SQL_Romanian_CP1250_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    English  NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
);
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT TestTable SELECT 1, N'da', 'yes';
INSERT TestTable SELECT 2, N'ani', 'years';
INSERT TestTable SELECT 3, N'a avea', 'to have';
INSERT TestTable SELECT 4, N'a fi', 'to be';
INSERT TestTable SELECT 5, N'șase', 'six';
INSERT TestTable SELECT 6, N'șapte', 'seven';
INSERT TestTable SELECT 7, N'opt', 'eight';  
INSERT TestTable SELECT 8, N'zece', 'ten';
INSERT TestTable SELECT 9, N'nu', 'no';
GO

SELECT *
FROM TestTable
WHERE Romanian LIKE 'a%';

USE master;
GO

DROP DATABASE TestDb;
GO
```

I was expecting this to return the following

```
+----+-------------+----------+
| Id | Romanian    | English  |
+----+-------------+----------+
| 2  | ani         | years    |
+----+-------------+----------+
| 3  | a avea      | to have  |
+----+-------------+----------+
| 4  | a fi        | to be    |
+----+-------------+----------+
```

but it returned this instead

```
+----+-------------+----------+
| Id | Romanian    | English  |
+----+-------------+----------+
| 2  | ani         | years    |
+----+-------------+----------+
| 3  | a avea      | to have  |
+----+-------------+----------+
| 4  | a fi        | to be    |
+----+-------------+----------+
| 5  | șase        | six      |
+----+-------------+----------+
| 6  | șapte       | seven    |
+----+-------------+----------+
```

The version number I have is 13.0.1601.5

Comment: if i use varchar i end up with ?ase and ?apte

Comment: @Paparazzi arbitrary value for example purposes. What difference does it make? I found this [Are there any disadvantages to always using nvarchar(MAX)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148398/are-there-any-disadvantages-to-always-using-nvarcharmax), aside from issues described there, might the use of MAX have any bearing to my issue?

Comment: Sorry I brought it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Collations are provided only for backward compatibility.

This has been the case [for over 10 years](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/322112).

Use a more modern collation such as `Romanian_100_CI_AS`.

This does not produce that behaviour.

Comment: Yes, definitely a collation problem.